# SQLI Login Bypass Cheat-sheets Question

Tags: web-application, php, sql-injection, mysql, injection

Assuming you are authorized to pentest a live website that's login page is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Lets say your backpack has only 2 crafted queries by you which is **`admin' --`** and **`'=' 'OR'`**.

Your past experience on a test site where its back-end SQL code is as simple as belows

**`select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$pass';`**

Yes! This 2 **`admin' --`**  and **`'=' 'OR'`** cheat-sheet in your backpack works for bypassing for the above SQL statement.

Okay! Now! Here comes the real live website for you to pentest.
But only this **`'=' 'OR'`** cheat-sheet in your backpack works instead of this **`admin' --`**

---

So best guess is this live website you are authorized to pentest on is having a different back-end SQL code implementation than the one I stated above and only is able to be bypassed by 1 crafted cheat-sheet in your backpack which is **`'=' 'OR'`** and not **`admin' --`**

My question now is **how do you picture** this back-end SQL query code? **Assuming you do not have access to the back-end code at all!**

**How do you make a report out of this?** Saying this cheat-sheet `'=' 'OR'` works but what about the back-end code that is vulnerable to it? **Since you do not know how the back-end code is implemented that is vulnerable** and you can't come up with a migitation or prevention approach report for it?

Comment: We investigate. Pen-testing is not about script-kidding by cheat sheets. It's all about intelligent investigation.

Comment: How much do you know of about the SQ language?  Start there.

Comment: Hmm looks like you guys are not answering my question. To prevent a long comment here. Please kindly skip to the last part for a summary instead.

Comment: I am trying to scope/clarify the question

Comment: @DarkMatter alright please do note I have fundamental SQL knowledge and know how SQLI works. I am just asking a different question , I tried my best to put it simple and used a little bit of analogy in it hopefully you guys understand me.

Comment: Looks like for some reason you are asking the [same question](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/207341/cash) over and over again

Comment: You are using some strange terms that are causing some confusion. `'='` is not a "cheatsheet"; it's an injection. A cheatsheet is just a collection of tips and tricks, which can include injections. What is "backpack"? What you appear to be asking is how to reverse engineer the backend SQL code or to make a guess as to what the SQL code might be. Then you seem to ask about a "report". Why do you need to know or guess what the code actually is for a report? What you are asking for is very confusing.

Comment: *"My question now is how do you picture this back-end SQL query code? Assuming you do not have access to the back-end code at all!"*  By making educated guesses or by making assumptions how the code might look like and knowing the programming language in and out which you try to attack.. see [this (post of mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809948/mariadb-sql-injection/54810875#54810875) for a example as i didnt know how the Hack The Box  code looked like but still got it right.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following contrived back end would satisfy your requirement:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers Where '$uid'='SuperUser'
```

Which becomes

```
SELECT * FROM Customers Where ''=''OR''='SuperUser'
```

As for preventing this sort of thing the answer is true for all SQLI.  Sanitize and validate all user inputs.

Comment: JFYI, "Sanitize and validate all user inputs" is not clear, and even being [the source of many injections](https://phpdelusions.net/top#escaping_user_input). All terms here are unclear and ambiguous. What is "sanitize"? Will escaping HTML entities be enough? How does "validate" actually help? Is a [static HTML form element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22534183/285587) a user input? A [data from your own database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134138/285587), already validated?

Comment: @YourCommonSense True but the "how to prevent injection" question has been asked and answered time and time again...It is a simple search away.  My answer is obviously focused on the specific question present here.